# Multi-Wireless Networking

Tags: networking, wireless

I'd just like to inquire if this is possible, i will get an ISP 1(Eastern 4 Mbps) and right now i have ISP 2(Globe 50 Mbps). I want to combine this two different ISP using a router so that i will have 54 Mbps wireless network connection ***if possible***. I also want to use my ISP 1 as my main connection and my ISP 2 as a back-up, if there will be problems. And right now, my concern is -- is it possible? My client machines are using Ubuntu 16.04 and right now i'm still searching what router i must use. I'm new in Ubuntu and just like to ask if this is possible. Any answer or clarification will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, not possible and not even practical. In corporate networks it's feasible and makes sense but such settings are way out of your and your hardware's and your services' league.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hi guys. Can we combine two different ISP using a router into one wireless network and whats the main procedure to look at first?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/870971/hi-guys-can-we-combine-two-different-isp-using-a-router-into-one-wireless-netwo)